# how to compare the exact time with entering time in python

Tags: python, tkinter

im a new beginner in python and im trying to get the user enter any time and compare it with the time being.When i try the coding below.the result of the clock didnt show the exact time.instead it print the different value.Much appreciated if you can help.

```
from Tkinter import*
from time import sleep
import time
import serial
root=Tk()
time1 = ''
clock = Label(font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='pink',fg='red')
print(clock)
clock.pack(fill=X,expand=1)
label=Label(text="Add New Time")
time_entry = Entry()
label.pack()
time_entry.pack()
def tick():
    global time1
    time2 = time.strftime('%H: %M')
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
    clock.after(200, tick)
def tick2():
   if clock == time_entry.get():
         print("Correct")
    else:
         print("Wrong")
    root.destroy()
button = Button(root,text="submit",command=tick2) 
button.pack()
tick()
root.mainloop(  )
```

[the red which i rounded is the value that dont show the exact time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtxjS.png)

Comment: You aren't using PyGTK+ here.  Therefore, I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right, the problem is that you are trying to convert `Label` to string representation here: `print(clock)`. While you want to get it's attribute referring to it's text content, which is `'text'`. So what you need to do is get the attribute using either:

```
print(clock['text'])
```

or

```
print(clock.cget('text'))
```

Also, here:

```
 def tick2():
   if clock == time_entry.get():
         print("Correct")
    else:
         print("Wrong")
    root.destroy()
```

you probably want to compare strings, so it's:

```
   if clock['text'] == time_entry.get():
         print("Correct")
    else:
         print("Wrong")
    root.destroy()
```

P.S. `time.strftime('%H: %M')` will give you time with a space, e.g. '11: 11' and not '11:11', so when comparing strings like these, it will return false for strings with and without the space.

Comment: @fathyeah, You are welcome! ) You might want to mark this answer as a solution since it helped.